# SQL: Case when being called in a where clause

Tags: sql, db2-400

I'm working with a pretty big query that I typed, but I going to shorten it on here. What I'm trying to do is select a bunch of columns and then run a case when and use a where not in clause to filter the results so I only see what a user is Authorized. If I remove the PERM NOT IN from my where clause it returns what a user is authorized and unauthorized for and I don't want to see that. I'm not 100% sure if it is possible and if it can be done another way or simpler that would be great.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT 
    usname AS Name, ususer AS Username, usseclevel AS Default_Level, 
    usglsecl AS GL_SecurityLevel, aoopid, aoseclevel
    CASE 
       WHEN aoauopid >= 00500 AND aoAuOpID < 10000 
          THEN
             CASE 
                WHEN usglsecl >= aoseclevel 
                   THEN 'Authorized' 
                   ELSE 'Unauthorized' 
             END
    END AS PERM
FROM
    library.file 
JOIN
    library.file ON usseclevel >= aoseclevel
WHERE 
    ususer NOT IN ('*ALL', 'daffron') 
    AND PERM NOT IN ('Unauthorized, 'null')
ORDER BY 
    ususer
```

If you would like for me to post my whole entire query I will, but I don't think it requires the whole query to get this desired output.

Comment: You cannot use the column alias in your `where` criteria like that.  Either repeat the `case` statement or use a `subquery`...

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here since I'm not sure which variant of SQL are you using. You can't normally use a column alias in the `WHERE` clause. Off the top of my head, I see three options:

**Option 1 - Use a "table expression" to produce a bona fide column name from the alias:**

```
select * from (
  Select usname as Name, ususer as Username, usseclevel as Default_Level, 
  usglsecl as GL_SecurityLevel, aoopid, aoseclevel
  Case When aoauopid >=00500 and aoAuOpID <10000 then case when 
  usglsecl>=aoseclevel then 'Authorized' else 'Unauthorized' end END AS PERM
  from library.file join library.file on usseclevel>=aoseclevel
  WHERE ususer NOT IN('*ALL','daffron') 
) x
WHERE PERM NOT IN('Unauthorized,'null')
ORDER BY ususer
```

**Option 2 - Use a CTE (Common Table Expression):**

```
with x as (
  Select usname as Name, ususer as Username, usseclevel as Default_Level, 
  usglsecl as GL_SecurityLevel, aoopid, aoseclevel
  Case When aoauopid >=00500 and aoAuOpID <10000 then case when 
  usglsecl>=aoseclevel then 'Authorized' else 'Unauthorized' end END AS PERM
  from library.file join library.file on usseclevel>=aoseclevel
  WHERE ususer NOT IN('*ALL','daffron') 
)
select * from x 
WHERE PERM NOT IN('Unauthorized,'null')
ORDER BY ususer
```

**Option 3 - Repeat the whole CASE again in the WHERE clause (instead of PERM):**

```
Select usname as Name, ususer as Username, usseclevel as Default_Level, 
usglsecl as GL_SecurityLevel, aoopid, aoseclevel
Case When aoauopid >=00500 and aoAuOpID <10000 then case when 
usglsecl>=aoseclevel then 'Authorized' else 'Unauthorized' end END AS PERM
from library.file join library.file on usseclevel>=aoseclevel
WHERE ususer NOT IN('*ALL','daffron') 
and Case When aoauopid >=00500 and aoAuOpID <10000 then case when 
usglsecl>=aoseclevel then 'Authorized' else 'Unauthorized' end END
    NOT IN('Unauthorized,'null')
ORDER BY ususer
```

Comment: This is again the big query alternative theres as such no reduction in the code.

Comment: I just want to mention one thing which may not be an issue here, but is sure to be an issue elsewhere. `NULL` cannot be tested inside an `IN` predicate. It can only be tested by `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`. Nulls are handled in a strange way. Since they mean 'no data', comparisons including `NULL`s do not return either true or false, so they don't satisfy any of the comparison predicates (`IN`, `NOT IN`, `BETWEEN`, `NOT BETWEEN`, `=`, `<>`, etc.)

Comment: So, to expand further, it looks like the OP is trying to exclude `NULL` as well as 'Unauthorized' in his `NOT IN` predicate. It would be excluded simply because a `NOT IN` cannot be satisfied by a `NULL`, even if 'null' (which is a string) is not specified. Understanding this, the `NOT IN` can be reduced to `<>`.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Maybe the filtering predicate `PERM NOT IN ('Unauthorized, 'null')` should be written as `PERM is not null and PERM <> 'Unauthorized'`. Write it as an answer to upvote it; you caught this one.